# How to change ImageButton drawable color when used as background programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-imagebutton

I have the following ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/nopeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/nope_button_states" />
```

Here is `nope_button_states`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/nope_button" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/nope_button_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/nope_button_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/nope_button" />
</selector>
```

Now I want to change the tint color of the drawable. When I use with:

```
android:src="@drawable/nope_button"
```

then I can do: `nopeButton.setColorFilter()` but this does not work anymore when using in background.

**How do I change the tint color from the ImageButton drawings when used with  background property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
nopeButton.getBackground().setColorFilter();
```

Comment: But the input is not just an int. What parameter do I have to use in order to change the drawing color?

Comment: It should not change the transaprent parts of the image.

Comment: try with setColorFilter(yourcolor, Mode.SRC_ATOP);

Comment: This works only one time. When I click the button the first time it's color changes but the second time nothing happened. Any idea?

Comment: I try to call setColorFilter inside onClick of a button and the background color changed correctly every time with a random color (i write a small piece of code to try). Can you post your onClick code?